# Keyboard is hidden on orientation change

Tags: android, keyboard, orientation-changes

My keyboard is hidden when the orientation of the android phone changes to landscape. What should I do in order to show my keyboard?

Answer (score 3):

Add this on your code

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

put this in **onCreate()** and **onResume()** in your class file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
 imm.showSoftInputFromWindow(enterChat.getWindowToken(), 0);

 getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

This will make your keyboard always visible. In this the enterchat is `editText` I have used. You don't need that thing i think.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you try AndroidManifest.xml

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"`  put this.