# Soft keyboard not retain while orientation change

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-orientation

I am opening the soft keyboard forcefully on a activity, but it is disappearing while i am change the orientation.

How can i fix it ?

Comment: Try looking at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6027578/1777090) post's answers. Might help. :)

Comment: Can you post your manifest? I'm guessing you have KeyboardHidden option selected on your Orientation options in manifest.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use onConfigurationChanged method of Activity. Please make sure your activity in menifest has android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
          android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Also in activity

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        // show keyboard
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        // show keyboard        
    }
}
```

Comment: it depends on your layout. if you have edittext control you can use this method to forcefully show it. InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.showSoftInput(yourEditText, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

Comment: and to hide it use.
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(yourEditText.getWindowToken(), 0);

Comment: I am mention in question i am opening keyboard forcefully without edittext , Tts appearing just tapping on a button.

Comment: My question is that how to retain the state of softkeyboad ?

Comment: you can use the same method to open it. once it is opened save the state in a variable. and when the orientation is changed open it or hide it depending upon the saved state i.e InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,0);

Comment: why are you suggesting me open/hide keyboard, i want to know maintaining state of keyboard ? whether it is hidden/visible ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in **onResume()** and **onPause()** of your activity

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Comment: Why in onPause() method ?